# SharePoint 2010 deployment problem after added a new server to existing farm

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, sharepoint-2010, visual-studio-2010

I have SharePoint 2010 farm with one server. I'm developing some features in a sharepoint farm solution (not sandbox because there are some user rights problem). All feature scopes are set to "Site". I can deploy the solution to SharePoint with no problem. I added a new web front-end server to my existing farm. Then when I try deploy my solution, VS2010 shows this error:

> Error occurred in deployment step
>   'Activate Features': Feature with Id
>   'xxx' is not installed in this farm,
>   and cannot be added to this scope

- I login with AD administrator account to
  development server.
- Administrator
  account is in site collection admins
  on the target web application.
- The farm account is in local
  administrators group.

Is there a solution for this error?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the solution in Visual Studio 2010 -> Package -> Package.Template.xml
2. Remove **DeploymentServerType="ApplicationServer"**
3. Now try to deploy

It should work.